# 161gb not appearing on diskutil after deleting second OSX partition

Tags: macos, mojave, disk-space, apfs, system-information

I deleted my second OSX partition and I'm missing 161gb of space. It's not appearing on diskutil or Disk Utility. I have to keep the Untitled2 partition because it stores files I need.

[image: Disk Utility Screensot]

diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         172.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         167.6 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +172.5 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Untitled2               141.5 GB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +167.6 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            108.3 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.0 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
```

diskutil apfs list

```
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 4CA49CB7-0B51-487F-AC91-843A00AACD56
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk1
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      172464693248 B (172.5 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   141663903744 B (141.7 GB) (82.1% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       30800789504 B (30.8 GB) (17.9% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s2 D50CC799-F508-4BC3-99B7-D88453067192
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
|   |   Size:                       172464693248 B (172.5 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s1 8FC2013D-3475-4D7A-B782-34120455DBEA
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
|       Name:                      Untitled2 (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               /Volumes/Untitled2
|       Capacity Consumed:         141533384704 B (141.5 GB)
|       FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
|
+-- Container disk2 525596F2-BF28-4B79-8A69-980E08DCA7B8
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk2
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      167607386112 B (167.6 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   110029500416 B (110.0 GB) (65.6% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       57577885696 B (57.6 GB) (34.4% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s3 E0DF7FC9-10C9-48EB-B1D3-955CF2604696
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s3
    |   Size:                       167607386112 B (167.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s1 1AD64FB4-1024-4B39-9429-B4A7493D28D7
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         108267294720 B (108.3 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s2 BB7D5886-DEB8-4044-BD11-477B9241B902
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         44994560 B (45.0 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s3 E0FCF8A4-B9EE-4933-A159-01FE53268518
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         512753664 B (512.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s4 0C55D779-851D-4F4A-BB98-31480E17A910
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         1073762304 B (1.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
```

diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size

```
   Partition Offset:          160205692928 Bytes (39112718 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 172.5 GB (172464693248 Bytes) (exactly 336845104 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes
```

diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Offset -e Size

```
   Partition Offset:          332670386176 Bytes (81218356 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 167.6 GB (167607386112 Bytes) (exactly 327358176 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes
```

The above information can be summerized in the table given below.

```
starting sector  ending sector  # of sectors  identifier
---------------  -------------  ------------  ---------- 
                                     ~76,806  disk0s1
     39,112,718     81,218,355    42,105,638  disk0s2
     81,218,356    122,138,127    40,919,772  disk0s3
```

Total number of sectors = ~122,143,554.
There are 4096 bytes per sector.

The largest block of free space occurs before `disk0s2` and `disk0s3` and can be approximated by the equation shown below.

```
(39,112,718 - 76,806) * 4096 = 159,891,095,552 bytes.
```

Comment: Excellent research. Can you confirm / upload `diskutil apfs list` so we can be sure you just need to remove the *disk0s3* container that's untitled2? I'll put up half an answer in case my comment isn't making sense.

Comment: OK - my answer helps you get to where you want. I don't see any missing space but I would get things off Untitled2 and move that to your main APFS container so you only have one going forward.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of back and forth in comments, it’s looking like you have a couple containers that won’t collapse back into one chunk of space, so you’ll want to live with this until such time as you make a backup, wipe the APFS containers, recreate one container and then re-make all your volumes in one APFS container and reinstall the OS / restore the data from backup.

---

I'm thinking you added a partition when you just needed to add a volume to the same container so all the volumes could share free space and not block each other from using the full free space:

[image]

If you clicked **Add Volume** you would only have one container and the Untitled2 volume would be quick and easy to delete and not take any space away from the other volumes in the same container.

[image: bootable volume - slim]

[image: Untitled2 volume]

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume slim                    199.5 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 65.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Untitled2               647.2 KB   disk1s5
```

In your case - the parts of **disk0** are mutually exclusive and the **disk0s3** is locking away 167.6 GB of space from the main container.

In my case, you can see that both volumes see the same amount of free space and you'll not have that flexibility since you have two high level "Containers" that can't share free space.

[image: System Information storage view from the About This Mac storage pane]

Assuming you just want to get rid of the second container are you more comfortable deleting from Disk Utility or the command line?

Comment: Hi, I have to keep the Untitled2 partition because it stores files I need

Comment: @leecan999 You might need to back it up, then erase and then recreate it. How full are each volume if you look at Finder? I'll upload copies to match my situation if that helps.

Comment: The amount of space left for Macintosh HD is 57.51 GB and for Untitled 2 it's 30.8 GB.

Comment: Now I'm getting the hang of your situation - so sorry it took a few steps. You have 500 GB total, 172.5 to disk1 and 167.6 to disk2 so you're "missing" 159.9. You could try to grow one or both of the physical stores and you'd have enough room if you could grow disk2 completely and copy the data from disk1 - then remove disk1 and then grow disk2 to 500 (ish). I'm curious how you got there, though - normally MacintoshHD is on disk1 which makes it easier to re-consolidate typically. BootCamp perhaps?

Comment: I created another partition > installed OSX, copied some files over > created another partition (Untitled2) from the old Macintosh HD, copied some more files to Untitled2 > deleted the old Macintosh HD and named the current Macintosh HD. That's why it's set up like this.

Comment: I would recommend before proceeding further that you post the output from the two commands: `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size` and `diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Offset -e Size` These command will not change your Mac. The location of the missing free space can be determined from the output.

Comment: @leecan999 have a look at providing David Anderson  information above. He might have a much more elegant solution for you.

Comment: @DavidAnderson details are in the main body of the question. Looks like both are located a bit back from the head of the partition.

Comment: The ~160 GB of free space is before `disk0s2` and `disk0s3`. The macOS operating system offers no practical method to add the free space to an existing partition.

Comment: So backup and wipe and set up one container is the way forward that’s easiest

Comment: @leecan999: Do you have way to backup everything you want to keep? For example, to a volume on an external drive or through the use of Time Machine. Otherwise, you would have to execute a complex set of commands where a third container would be created from the free space. Maybe reinstall macOS to the new container. Afterwards, you would have to copy files (or clone volumes), followed by removing and resizing containers. So taking bmike's advice, to backup and wipe and set up one container, would be easier.

Comment: I don't but I have all the files. I'll just have to get an external hd, transfer and wipe my mac, then finally set up time machine for the future. Thank you guys.

Comment: There’s a chance you can make a new container and it would land at the beginning of the disk if you made it small enough. Then you could remove the first container - grow the new container, and spend a whole lot of time. I’ll edit my answer to have a summary at the top what’s been figured in the comments.